# Yocto find the recipe or class that defines a task

Tags: yocto, xilinx, device-tree

I am a yocto noob, trying to decipher how the device tree is built from a Xilinx hardware definition (.hdf) file. But my question is more general.

Is there a yocto way to find the source of task?
Given a task name is it possible to find where the tasks source code lives? (presumably in a recipe or class)

As an example, where is the source for the Python task do_create_yaml which is called by recipes in the meta-xilinx-bsp layer that compile the device tree blob?

```
bitbake -e device-tree
```

Will dump the python source for do_create_yaml (amongst the rest of it prodigious output) but how can I find where that is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the datastore contains the filename for tasks as a VarFlag,
from a devpyshell

```
pydevshell> d.getVarFlags("do_create_yaml")
```

gives

```
{'filename': '.....yocto/sources/core/../meta-xilinx-tools/classes/xsctyaml.bbclass', 'lineno': '61', 'func': 1, 'task': 1, 'python': '1', 'deps':   ['do_prepare_recipe_sysroot']}
```

So for the example in my question the active definition for the do_create_yaml task is in xsctyaml.bbclass.

Answer (score 0):

Device tree is part of Linux Kernel. In Yocto, this is compiled from `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` variable value either defined as part of Linux Kernel recipe or machine configuration.

For example, for cubieboard7 as defined [here](https://github.com/Linumiz/meta-actions/blob/master/conf/machine/cubieboard7.conf#L26),

```
KERNEL_DEVICETREE = "s700_cb7_linux.dtb"
```

instructs the compilation to use [this](https://github.com/Linumiz/linux/blob/cubieboard7/arch/arm64/boot/dts/s700_cb7_linux.dts) dts file for compilation. This is done by yocto by using various classes.

In [our example](https://github.com/Linumiz/meta-actions/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/linux.inc#L6), we `inherit kernel.bbclass` which in turn `inherits kernel-devicetree.bbclass`, in this class (copied from kernel-devicetree.bbclass),

```
do_compile_append() {
        for dtbf in ${KERNEL_DEVICETREE}; do
                dtb=`normalize_dtb "$dtbf"`
                oe_runmake $dtb
        done
}

do_install_append() {
        for dtbf in ${KERNEL_DEVICETREE}; do
                dtb=`normalize_dtb "$dtbf"`
                dtb_ext=${dtb##*.}
                dtb_base_name=`basename $dtb .$dtb_ext`
                dtb_path=`get_real_dtb_path_in_kernel "$dtb"`
                install -m 0644 $dtb_path ${D}/${KERNEL_IMAGEDEST}/$dtb_base_name.$dtb_ext
        done
}

do_deploy_append() {
        for dtbf in ${KERNEL_DEVICETREE}; do
                dtb=`normalize_dtb "$dtbf"`
```

this appends tasks to compile, install and deploy tasks. So defining `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` enables the automatic build of dtb.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have changed the rewording of the question as it conflates the question with an example related to the device tree. My question is "Is there a way to find where a task is defined, where its source code lives?" BTW: For Xilinx SoCs the device-tree situation is complicated by the fact that devices can be implemented in the programmable logic (PL), the blob (.dtb) is compiled from a .dts constructed from .dtsi fragments one of which contains information from the hardware definition (.hdf) for the PL.

Comment: @Codemonkey: So you want to know the location of `do_compile`, `do_configure` and similar tasks?

Comment: Yes, though I am more interested in the non OE default ones, the custom ones. The -e flag to bitbake gives you the environment for a recipe including the active task definitions, but no clue as to where the definition came from. I am wondering if there is a way to find that out.